# How to make rx.el regexps non greedy?

Tags: regular-expressions, rx

Here is my expression:

```
(setq myregexp (rx bol
                   "####"
                   (one-or-more anything)
                   "."))
```

This should match *any string starting with "####"*, spanning over *zero or mode new lines*, and **stop at the first found "."** right?

This is my test buffer:

```
#### This.
#### This too.
#### And also
this.
#### Oh, and this too.
But not this.
```

And here is the fn that I use to test it:

```
(defun regtest ()
  "search"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (while
        (re-search-forward myregexp nil t nil)
      (message "Found [%s] and [%s]" (match-string 0) (match-string 1)))))
```

But here is what it returns:

```
Found [#### This.
#### This too.
#### And also
this.
#### Oh, and this too.] and [nil]
```

How can I make the regexp **stop at the first found match** of the last `rx` expression? And more generally, how to properly use `anything`?

Comment: In general when I use regular expressions, if I want to match everything up to the first ".", I replace "anything" by "[^.]". With rx, have you tried "minimal-match"?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri `minimal-match` worked ; you should make it an answer so I can accept it ; it's a big deal, I mean, that was my last gripe about `rx.el` and I think everybody wants to know about this one, you do realize **there is no rx.el documentation apart from the very lib header**? :) Thanks!

Comment: Her is the expression that worked, you can use it in your answer: `
(setq myregexp-interactive (rx bol
                               "####"
                               (minimal-match
                                (and
                                 (one-or-more anything)
                                 "."))
                               ))
`

Comment: Regarding the documentation: Have you checked `C-h f rx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general when I use regular expressions, if I want to match everything up to the first ".", I replace `anything` by "[^.]". With rx, if you want to use `anything`, I suggest using `minimal-match`. This apparently succeeds (worked out by @yPhil):

```
(setq myregexp-interactive (rx bol 
                               "####" 
                               (minimal-match (and (one-or-more anything) ".")) ))
```

Note that I discovered `minimal-match` by reading the source code, not because of any documentation for `rx`.

Comment: `minimal-match` is also in the `rx` docstring. Other possibly relevant things in the docstring: `rx-greedy-flag` and `+?` which is described as "like `one-or-more`, but always produces a non-greedy regexp."

Comment: Good to know. I think in a perfect world, `rx` would be covered in the Elisp info page. I couldn't find it there.

Comment: The `rx` equivalent for `[^.]` is `(not (any "."))`, so the whole regex would be `(rx bol "####" (one-or-more (not (any "."))) ".")`.